# Is it normal that cooking time of my pizza is 1 hour in oven with 230 degrees?

Tags: oven, cooking-time, pizza

I know its wired but i need to keep my pizza for one hour in oven with 230 Celsius degrees to properly cook it
but everyone says 20 minutes or less is enough
i don't know why it takes so long for me

sorry for bad English its not my native language

Comment: There are many styles of pizza, how are you making it?  Do you cook it in a pan?  How thick?  Also, for how long do you let your oven pre-heat before putting the pizza in?

Comment: Are you sure that your oven is really at 230 Celsius? In other words, did you check the oven temperature with an oven thermometer?

Comment: Preheating is important. I cook my pizza on a pizza stone which I preheat for ONE HOUR on FULL WHACK before I put the  in. Takes 8 minutes then to finish.

Comment: And we're talking fresh pizza, not frozen, right? My mom had that gas oven and a frozen pizza took there for ages to finish. Oven type is also interesting.

Comment: And your English is fine. Says another non-native speaker ;-)

Comment: thank you all for your answers , i use a gas oven and yes i pre heat oven my pizza is usually 1.5 - 2 cm thick , no im not sure that my oven is 230 degrees because i don't have thermometer and my pizza is fresh not frozen

Comment: That is quite a thick pizza, but it still shouldn't take that long.  Does the pizza actually brown on top in that time?  Is it possible your oven is calibrated in Fahrenheit instead of Celsius?

Comment: Another thought: Is it running on the right gas, at the right pressure? An oven designed for piped gas (methane) won't work well on butane/propane, and an oven that shares a long thin pipe with a lot of other things will be rather pathetic too.

Comment: Are you using any kind of pizza stone? For reference: A thin, fresh pizza on a stone in a 250-270°C oven is usually perfect in 6 to 7 minutes.

Comment: I realize this is far fetched, but is there any possibility you're actually using 230 F instead of 230 C?  Some ovens allow you to switch which system they use and don't necessarily display the F or C.

Answer (score 6):

One hour sounds like a long time for a 1.5 to 2 cm thick pizza at that temperature, regardless of the style of pizza.  I would begin by locating an oven thermometer to check the temperature of your oven.

Comment: Indeed. 230*C is almost 450*F for us Americans -- that's a long time at that temperature! If it was truly at 230*C, even the most overloaded toppings-piled pizza would be burnt solid in an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds wrong to me. I would expect a pizza like that, at that temperature to cook in more like 8-12 minutes and almost certainly be burnt by the 15 minute mark. Do other things take long times to cook in your oven? Could your oven be faulty?

Also are you using a recipe for your pizza? What does the recipe say? All things to check.

Answer (score -5):

This temp, essentially 450 F is a reasonable temp for crispy pizza crust in certain conditions.

thin crust, not too much sauce. You are OK.

Really, good crisp pizza wants high temp and short times to get dough spring and fast melting.

Crank the oven and cook for just a couple minutes.

Comment: Downvotes without explanation?

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but I think I know why some people did. The OP seems to be asking if anybody had any ideas why his pizza is not cooking within the expected time frame. I don't think you addressed that question.